# Bundle product JavaScript errors in console

Tags: magento-1, javascript, bundled-product, html

My bundled products aren't working properly.

On loading the product page it already goes wrong with the following error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadPrice' of undefined`

When i select an option from the drop-down box, the amount field stays grayed out and i get an error in the console (Google Chrome) stating:

`Uncaught TypeError Cannot change property of 'changeSelection' of undefined`

The HTML from the amount field has the property `disabled=""disabled"`, I guess this is supposed to change on making your selection thus enabling you to change the amount for the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Magentos `bundle.js` is not included properly. Since this is part of the default theme, you are probably using a custom theme that includes its own broken bundle.js or does not load it in the layout XML at all.

The theme might just not be compatible with your Magento version, please contact the theme provider to get an updated/fixed version.